# Why doesn't python Dajaxice function recognize when HTML sends argument(s)?

Tags: python, django, dajaxice

This works:

```
Javascript:
    function my_js_callback(data) {alert("Response = " + data.response);}
HTML:
    <input id="myID" type="text" name="myID" onblur="Dajaxice.myApp.myAjaxFunction(my_js_callback);"/>
Python:
    @dajaxice_register()
    def myAjaxFunction(request):
        return simplejson.dumps({'response': True})
```

However, when I add an argument to the Ajax function and it's call from HTML, it doesn't work:

```
Javascript:
    function my_js_callback(data) {alert("Response = " + data.response);}
HTML:
    <input id="myID" type="text" name="myID" onblur="Dajaxice.myApp.myAjaxFunction(my_js_callback,{'myArgument':3});"/>
Python:
    @dajaxice_register()
    def myAjaxFunction(request, myArgument):
        return simplejson.dumps({'response': True})
```

Here is the error it produces:

```
TypeError: myAjaxFunction() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Why doesn't the second argument get passed to myAjaxFunction()? How do I make myAjaxFunction recognize what I'm trying to send it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I needed to add method='GET' to the decorator. Then it worked:

```
@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
```